# IOS/Swift/Bluemix: Convert curl request to IBM Watson to AlamoFire Request in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-cloud, alamofire

I am able to access the Watson Tone Analyzer API from a web page using the following code written in PHP using CURL:

```
   $username='long-user-name';
     $password='my-password';
     $data = json_encode(array('text' => 'All you need is love'));
$URL = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2016-05-19';
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);          
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

     $result=curl_exec ($ch);
     curl_close ($ch);
 echo $result;
```

IBM/Watson does not provide sample code for accessing API through Swift or AlamoFire for IOS although their Swift SDK apparently uses AlamoFire.  I am not downloading their SDK because it requires carthage and has other dependencies that people report as causing problems.  However, you are supposed to be able to request the API using AlamoFire.

The following code that I tried gives a 401 error for bad authentication.  Can anyone from the IBM Bluemix team or elsewhere suggest how to convert the above working curl to a valid AlamoFire request?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

My code that returns 401 for bad authentication:

```
func postToWatson () {
            print("post to watson called")
            let url: String =  "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2016-05-19"
            let message = "All you need is love"
            var parameters = [
               "username":"my-username",
                "password":"my-password"]
            parameters["text"] = message
            Alamofire.request(url, parameters: parameters)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.request)
                    print(response.response)
                    print(response.result)
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to set an HTTP Basic auth header with your username and password. That's what the PHP code does.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610581/ios-ibm-cloud-swift-post-to-watson-api-using-alamofire/50610913

Comment: @data_henrik.  It is not a duplicate of the other one because I provide CURL code here that works.

Comment: Mihai do you know how to do that in AlamoFire?

Comment: OK.  Managed to get 200 response by changing code to:  Alamofire.request(url,parameters:parameters).authenticate(user: username, password: password).responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.request)
                    print(response.response)
                    print(response.result)  taken from this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494157/basic-authentication-with-alamofire

Comment: Still not getting correct response from API but authentication problem solved.  Thx!